# maximum pairwise product fast solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, stress-testing

I am trying to apply a stress test on python maximum pairwise product, fast and slow algorithm. However, The fast code appears to return a wrong result in some tests. I think the problem comes from the if condition in the fast algorithm. The condition doesn't occur in some cases, though it should be applies. I wasn't able to figure out the problem. any help?

Here is the problem, I/P, O/P details:

> > Given a sequence of non-negative integers a0,…,an−1, find the maximum pairwise product, that is, the largest integer that can be obtained by multiplying two different elements from the sequence (or, more formally, max0≤i≠j≤n−1aiaj). Different elements here mean ai and aj with i≠j (it can be the case that ai=aj).
>
> Input format
>
> > The first line of the input contains an integer n. The next line contains n non-negative integers a0,…,an−1 (separated by spaces).
>
> Constraints:
>
> > 2≤n≤2⋅105; 0≤a0,…,an−1≤105.
>
> Output format:
>
> > Output a single number — the maximum pairwise product.

```
from random import randint
from random import randrange


def max_pairwise(n,a):
  #  n = int(input())
    res = 0
 #   a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    assert(len(a) == n)

    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if a[i]*a[j] > res:
                res = a[i]*a[j]

    return(res)
    

def max_pairwise_fast(n,a):
 #   n = int(input())
 #   a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

    max_index1 = -1
    max_index2 = -1

    for i in range(0,n):
        if a[i] > a[max_index1]:
            max_index1 = i
        else:
            continue

    for j in range(0,n):
        if ((a[j] != a[max_index1]) and (a[j] > a[max_index2])):
            max_index2 = j
        else:
            continue

    res = a[max_index1]* a[max_index2]
    return(res)

    
#stress_test
while(1):
    n = randint(0,9) +2
    print(n,"n")
    a = []
    for i in range (n):
        a.append(randrange(9000))
    for i in range(n):
        print(a[i],'a[i]',"/n")
    if (max_pairwise(n,a) == max_pairwise_fast(n,a)):
        print(max_pairwise(n,a), max_pairwise_fast(n,a),"true")
    else:
        print(max_pairwise(n,a), max_pairwise_fast(n,a), "false")
        break
```

This is an example of the result:

```
6 n
318 a[i] /n
7554 a[i] /n
7531 a[i] /n
7362 a[i] /n
4783 a[i] /n
4897 a[i] /n
56889174 56889174 true
5 n
6879 a[i] /n
6985 a[i] /n
8561 a[i] /n
5605 a[i] /n
3077 a[i] /n
59798585 59798585 true
9 n
8285 a[i] /n
3471 a[i] /n
2280 a[i] /n
2443 a[i] /n
5437 a[i] /n
2605 a[i] /n
1254 a[i] /n
6990 a[i] /n
2943 a[i] /n
57912150 68641225 false
```

Answer (score 3):

In your fast implementation, when you are finding a largest number, **you must also update the second largest to the value of the previous largest**, otherwise, there are cases where you end up multiplying numbers that are not the two largest.

```
def product_of_two_largest(seq):
    largest = float("-inf")
    second_largest = float("-inf")

    for elt in seq:
        if elt > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = elt
        elif elt > second_largest:
            second_largest = elt
    return second_largest * largest
```

#### Note 1:

Your while loop must also be updated, you are calculating the values twice instead of once.

```
while(1):
    n = randint(0,9) +2
    print(n,"n")
    a = []
    for i in range (n):
        a.append(randrange(9000))
    for i in range(n):
        print(a[i],'a[i]',"/n")

    slow, fast = max_pairwise(n, a), two_largest_product(a)

    if (slow == fast):
        print(slow, fast, slow == fast)
    else:                                 # attention, this never happens now.
        break
```

#### Note 2:

As we are dealing with only **non-negative** integers, you will likely have a faster implementation if you simply sort the sequence and multiply the last two numbers (in spite of the fact that sort is `O(nlogn)`, vs `O(n)` for the fast implementation above.

```
b = sorted(a)
print("max1 x max2 = ", b[-1] * b[-2])
```

#### Note 3:

Using a `heap` data structure (`from collections import heap`) is the theoretical best way to find the n largest items, but you'd likely need to have `100,000's` of items to make it worth your while.

Comment: There are a number of MOOCs on coursera and EDx that teach algorithms and data structures at different levels and from various angles.

Comment: In product_of_two_largest() I do not understand why do we have to do it. My problem is that the maximum number is multiplied by itself in some cases and I do not know how it happens when I have this condition: if( j != max_index1).

Comment: It happens for the reason I gave you: you must update the second largest to the value of the previous largest when you encounter a new largest.

Answer (score 2):

```
def max_pairwise_fast(n, a):
    max_index1 = 0
    max_index2 = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] > max_index1:
            max_index2 = max_index1
            max_index1 = a[I]
        elif a[i] > max_index2:
            max_index2 = a[I]
    return max_index1 * max_index2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_n = int(input())
    input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(max_pairwise_fast(input_n, input_numbers))
```

Comment: what is `a[I]`?

Answer (score 0):

This might not help you.
I was attempting this question at Coursera ( Assignment ) and found that we don't need to make the solution more complex. We can simply store the first two largest integers while scanning from the user and print their product. A complex solution is the main reason for the TLE error.
code in c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long n, a = 0, b = 0, i = 0, numb = 1;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lld", &numb);
        if(numb >= a){
            b = a;
            a = numb;
        }
        else if(numb > b)
            b = numb;
    }
    printf("%lld", a * b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With input array data:
Example: [1, 2, 3]

```
def max(arr):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if a == 0 & arr[i]>a:
            a = arr[i]
        else:
            if arr[i]>a:
                b = a
                a = arr[i]
            else:
                if arr[i]>b: 
                    b = arr[i]
            
    return a*b;
```

Comment: The question was about Python?

Comment: @tconbeer I have already updated it on python

Comment: If you want to get upvotes (and avoid downvotes), note that code-only answers are frowned upon. Explain what you’ve done and why it’s an improvement on or at least a viable alternative to other answers.

Answer (score -2):

```
def max_pairwise_fast(n, a):
    max_index1 = 0
    max_index2 = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] > max_index1:
            max_index2 = max_index1
            max_index1 = a[i]
        elif a[i] > max_index2:
            max_index2 = a[i]
    return max_index1 * max_index2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_n = int(input())
    input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(max_pairwise_fast(input_n, input_numbers))
```

Comment: code-only answers are usually discouraged. TRy to explain the answer, so you don't get additional downvotes like mine